# react-big-calendar drag and drop

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-big-calendar

I am really new to react and in need of help.
I tried using the [dndOutsideSource.js](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html?path=/docs/addons-drag-and-drop--example-3) source to make a calendar that you can drag and drop to get a new event.

I am not quite sure how to use it though.

I left only the relevant parts to me in my code, and I am trying to call the function from another function.
I get the following error:
[cannot read properties format of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYKv2.png)

[This is how I called it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XZsw.png)

Would appreciate any help. thank you!
this is my code

```js
// @ts-ignore
import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useState } from 'react'
// @ts-ignore
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Calendar, Views, DateLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar'
import withDragAndDrop from 'react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop'
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop/styles.scss'
import events from './events'


const DragAndDropCalendar = withDragAndDrop(Calendar)

const adjEvents = events.map((it, ind) => ({
    ...it,
    isDraggable: ind % 2 === 0,
}))

const formatName = (name, count) => `${name} ID ${count}`

export default function DnDOutsideResource({ localizer}) {
    const [myEvents, setMyEvents] = useState(adjEvents)
    const [draggedEvent, setDraggedEvent] = useState()
    const [displayDragItemInCell, setDisplayDragItemInCell] = useState(true)
    const [counters, setCounters] = useState({ item1: 0, item2: 0 })

    const eventPropGetter = useCallback(
        (event) => ({
            ...(event.isDraggable
                ? { className: 'isDraggable' }
                : { className: 'nonDraggable' }),
        }),
        []
    )
    const handleDragStart = useCallback((event) => setDraggedEvent(event), [])

    const dragFromOutsideItem = useCallback(() => draggedEvent, [draggedEvent])

    const customOnDragOver = useCallback(
        (dragEvent) => {
            // check for undroppable is specific to this example
            // and not part of API. This just demonstrates that
            // onDragOver can optionally be passed to conditionally
            // allow draggable items to be dropped on cal, based on
            // whether event.preventDefault is called
            if (draggedEvent !== 'undroppable') {
                console.log('preventDefault')
                dragEvent.preventDefault()
            }
        },
        [draggedEvent]
    )


    const moveEvent = useCallback(
        ({ event, start, end, isAllDay: droppedOnAllDaySlot = false }) => {
            const { allDay } = event
            if (!allDay && droppedOnAllDaySlot) {
                event.allDay = true
            }

            // @ts-ignore
            setMyEvents((prev) => {
                const existing = prev.find((ev) => ev.id === event.id) ?? {}
                const filtered = prev.filter((ev) => ev.id !== event.id)
                return [...filtered, { ...existing, start, end, allDay }]
            })
        },
        [setMyEvents]
    )

    const newEvent = useCallback(
        (event) => {
            setMyEvents((prev) => {
                const idList = prev.map((item) => item.id)
                const newId = Math.max(...idList) + 1
                return [...prev, { ...event, id: newId }]
            })
        },
        [setMyEvents]
    )

    const onDropFromOutside = useCallback(
        ({ start, end, allDay: isAllDay }) => {
            if (draggedEvent === 'undroppable') {
                setDraggedEvent(null)
                return
            }

            const { name } = draggedEvent
            const event = {
                title: formatName(name, counters[name]),
                start,
                end,
                isAllDay,
            }
            setDraggedEvent(null)
            setCounters((prev) => {
                const { [name]: count } = prev
                return {
                    ...prev,
                    [name]: count + 1,
                }
            })
            newEvent(event)
        },
        [draggedEvent, counters, setDraggedEvent, setCounters, newEvent]
    )

    const resizeEvent = useCallback(
        ({ event, start, end }) => {
            // @ts-ignore
            setMyEvents((prev) => {
                const existing = prev.find((ev) => ev.id === event.id) ?? {}
                const filtered = prev.filter((ev) => ev.id !== event.id)
                return [...filtered, { ...existing, start, end }]
            })
        },
        [setMyEvents]
    )

    const defaultDate = useMemo(() => new Date(2015, 3, 12), [])

    return (
                <DragAndDropCalendar
                    defaultDate={defaultDate}
                    defaultView={Views.MONTH}
                    dragFromOutsideItem={
                        displayDragItemInCell ? dragFromOutsideItem : null
                    }
                    draggableAccessor="isDraggable"
                    eventPropGetter={eventPropGetter}
                    events={myEvents}
                    localizer={localizer}
                    onDropFromOutside={onDropFromOutside}
                    onDragOver={customOnDragOver}
                    onEventDrop={moveEvent}
                    onEventResize={resizeEvent}
                    onSelectSlot={newEvent}
                    resizable
                    selectable
                />
    )
}
DnDOutsideResource.propTypes = {
    localizer: PropTypes.instanceOf(DateLocalizer),
}
```

I tried calling the function in different ways, pass a default localizer